# Multiple queries in a pl/sql fuction

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function in pl/sql where I want to have three queries, each one will set a variable (exist,withdrawn and dates) and the string returned depends on the combination of this variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cat_status (systemId IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    status      VARCHAR2 (2000) := 'Null';
    exist       NUMBER := 1;
    withdrawn   NUMBER := 0;
    dates       NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
          SELECT DISTINCT result
            INTO exist
            FROM SEEDTEST_RESULT
           WHERE     SEEDTEST_RESULT.RESULT = '1'
                 AND SEEDTEST_RESULT.TEST_TYPE = 'C'
                 AND SEEDTEST_RESULT.SLRN_ID = systemId;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
            exist := 1;
    END;

    BEGIN
      SELECT 1
        INTO withdrawn
        FROM CROP
       WHERE     CROP.SYSTEM_ID = systemId
             AND NVL ( (CROP.ORIG_AREA - NVL (CROP.ADD_AREA, 0)), 0) = 0;

   EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        withdrawn := 1;
   END;

   BEGIN
      SELECT DATE_3_PROC  --replaced with 1 and works
        INTO dates
        FROM CROP
       WHERE CROP.SYSTEM_ID = systemId;
   EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        dates := 1;
   END;

    IF (dates = 0 AND withdrawn = 1)
    THEN
        status := 'NO RESULT';
    END IF;

    IF (dates = 1 AND exist = 1)
    THEN
        status := 'REJECTED';
    END IF;

    RETURN (status);
END get_cat_status;
```

I have tried to added them but so far it's not working. Can anybody help please?

Comment: What isn't working exactly?

Comment: you don't need a `group by` without any aggregate function.

Comment: Is compiling with warnings. I added the second query and it's also working but still struggling with the third one. I'm not familiar with the debugging in PL/SQL

Comment: Thanks @SudiptaMondal, I had a count previously. I removed them.

Comment: @Nils you need to post the latest code and the error message, you can write `SHOW ERRORS;` after compiling the package, it will give you the error messages.

Comment: I just changed the DATE_3_PROC to 1 as in the second query and it's working. I don't know the reason behind this, the query works well as a stand alone query.

Comment: Sorry I'm messing up with this question, it seems fine now but I would like to understand why. Thanks.

Comment: @Nils I'm sceptical about your second `BEGIN END`, the one you're using to fill `withdrawn` variable. It's seams like you're giving it value 1 regardless of data in table -  you are giving it value 1 if there is some data in table `CROP` that fulfills the conditions in `WHERE clause`, but then again giving it value 1 even if it doesn't (via your `NO_DATA_FOUND exception handling`).

Comment: Thanks @GoranKutlaca, I see the problem. This comes from a function in an Access application that I have to replicate in Oracle. Going back to the original function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is doing what I want now. Before the third query didn't work because DATE_3_PROC is a date and I was assigning this to **dates**, a number. In the original Access application it just check that there were no records returned for each query and updated the respective variable. In Oracle I mixed that up with the **into**, which already assign the value to the variable, and it didn't make sense. Now, when the query doesn't return any record I assign 0 instead of 1, and it will be one when there is a record.

```
Create or replace FUNCTION get_cat_status(systemId IN Number) 
 RETURN VARCHAR2 
 AS 
   status VARCHAR2(2000) := ' ';
   exist NUMBER;
   withdrawn NUMBER;
   dates NUMBER;
 BEGIN 

  BEGIN
   SELECT DISTINCT 1 INTO exist
   FROM SEEDTEST_RESULT
   WHERE SEEDTEST_RESULT.RESULT = '1'
     AND SEEDTEST_RESULT.TEST_TYPE = 'C'
     AND SEEDTEST_RESULT.SLRN_ID = systemId;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       exist := 0;  
   END;  

   BEGIN      
     SELECT 1 INTO withdrawn
    FROM CROP
    WHERE CROP.SYSTEM_ID = systemId
      AND NVL((CROP.ORIG_AREA - NVL(CROP.ADD_AREA, 0)), 0) = 0;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        withdrawn := 0;  
  END;

  BEGIN
    SELECT 1 INTO dates 
    FROM CROP
    WHERE CROP.SYSTEM_ID = systemId;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dates := 0;  
  END;      

  IF (dates = 1 and withdrawn = 0) THEN 
    status := 'NO RESULT';
  END IF;
  IF (dates = 0 and exist = 0) THEN 
    status := 'REJECTED';
  END IF;

  RETURN(status); 

END get_cat_status;
```